# Ants over a floating sphere

Tags: geometry

A floating stationary sphere of a certain size has 5 ants on its surface.  All ants must move at the same fixed speed and never change their initial direction vector. During the move, they must not be closer than 72.5 degrees (or surface distance of approximately sphere radius x 1.26536) one to another.  The ants are identified from 'A' to 'E'.  Is it possible to create an algorithm to plan the ants movement, position and direction, and view the solution in 3D?

Comment: What is "a floating stationary sphere"?

Comment: By "direction vector" do you mean in three dimensions?  So the ants move off the sphere?  Or do you mean they move on a great circle on the sphere?

Comment: "Floating Stationary Sphere" means a sphere in space, no supports, no wires and not rotating at all. "Direction Vector" is the great circle on the sphere, and no, they don't move off the sphere.

Comment: @WagnerLipnharski why 74 degrees? If you said 72 degrees you could space them on a single great circle.

Comment: @WillJagy That's probably precisely the reason why 74°

Comment: Based on my own question, I found out that the smaller surface will be a triangle made by three ants.  In this case, I found nine possible combinations among ants A through F.  I believe a geometrical object (kind of a net over the sphere) with nine faces is a enneahedron,  The connections would be  ABC, ABD, ABE, BCD, BCE, BDE, ACD, ACE and ADE.  It is very difficult for me to visualize such structure and even calculate distances.   Yes, the 74° is just to avoid the obvious solution.

Comment: Assuming here, correct me if wrong. Considering the nine triangles are isosceles, covering the whole sphere, each triangle area = 4.PI.r² / 9.  Lets consider the sphere's r =10 units, so area will be = 1256.63 units, each triangle will have 139.62 units.  The isosceles triangle area = side * height, in this case side² = area / sin(60°), then side = 12.69 units, or, radius * 1.269.   Now i need to get a plastic ball and a marker to see if it really fits.   I am not here considering the curvature of the area. This will be the first step, visualize the ants perfectly distributed over the sphere.

Comment: How can these triangles stay fixed in time, if ants must travel along great circles?

Comment: In addition, I don't understand how these triangles could help. To arrange five ants on a sphere at the largest distance among them you simply have to put two at the poles and the other three evenly spaced around the equator. But they cannot keep their mutual position fixed in time.

Comment: My idea is for the ants to form triangles at the start, since it appears to be the farthest they can be one from another.  Based on my previous post, triangle side to be radius * 1.269, it is smaller than what I post on the problem description ( radius * 1.2915), the minimum angle then must be 72.7°, for the fun of it and allow some slack among them, I could reduce it to 72.5° = radius * 1.26536 (I am editing the text on the problem).

Comment: In the setting I suggested there are only 6 triangles, not 9, to cover the whole sphere. And angles are 90° or more.

Comment: Aretino, you are correct.  If you align three ants over the equator, there will be no triangles among them, only from them to the two over the poles, making only 6 triangles.  The ones in the equator will be distanced 120°, and from them to the poles 90°.  But the ones in the poles could never travel (pole to pole) in between the ones in the equator, for the angle between them will become 60°.

Answer (score 1):

A few considerations (not a solution):

Consider an ant passing through the north pole at time $0$ and walking on the "Greenwich meridian"
$$ r_A(t)=\begin{bmatrix}0\\\sin t\\\cos t\end{bmatrix}$$
and another ant on the meridian $\alpha$ and with a phase difference $\phi$ (where $-180^\circ\le\alpha\le180^\circ$, ):
$$ r_B(t)=\begin{bmatrix}\sin \alpha\sin( t-\phi)\\\cos \alpha \sin (t-\phi)\\\cos (t-\phi)\end{bmatrix}.$$
Then 
$$\begin{align}(r_a(t)-r_B(t))^2&=
\sin^2 \alpha\sin^2( t-\phi)+(\cos \alpha \sin (t-\phi)-\sin t)^2+(\cos (t-\phi)-\cos t)^2\\
&=2-2\cos \alpha \sin (t-\phi)\sin t-2\cos(t-\phi)\cos t\\
&=2-\cos \alpha\, (\cos \phi -\cos(2t-\phi))-(\cos\phi+\cos(2t-\phi))\\
&=2-\cos \alpha \cos \phi-\cos\phi +(\cos\alpha-1)\cos(2t-\phi)).
\end{align} $$
Then clearly
$$ \min_{t\in\Bbb R}(r_a(t)-r_B(t))^2=1-\cos \alpha \cos \phi-\cos\phi +\cos\alpha=(1+\cos\alpha)(1-\cos\phi)$$
We must pick $\alpha, \phi$ so that this expression is $\ge 2(1-\cos74^\circ)$, the value obtained for $\alpha=0$ and $\phi=74^\circ$.
Thus for given $\alpha$, we need
$$ \cos\phi\le 1-\frac{2(1-\cos74^\circ)}{1+\cos\alpha},$$
and this is possible only if $\frac{2(1-\cos74^\circ)}{1+\cos\alpha}\le 2$, or
$$|\alpha|\le 106^\circ .$$
In particular, for $\alpha=90^\circ$ we obtain
$ \cos\phi\le -1+2\cos74^\circ$, or $|\phi|>116.6619\ldots ^\circ$.

While all these restrictions do give some leeway for *two* of the ants, it seems hard to find a configuration suitable for five ants. For example, the last result shows that an ant travelling on a meridian allows at most two ants travelling on the equator; any somewhat regular pattern seems to be prohibited (e.g., three meridians at $0°, 120°, 240°$ with one ant each and two ants on the equator? Prohibited by $|\alpha|<106°$). This alone does not yet make a solution impossible, but I am not very confoident ...

Comment: I see any two ants traveling over the same great circle must be spaced no less than 72.5° * 2, in order to allow another ant traveling another great circle in other angle to cross the first one (equator vs meridian, or any other inclination, for example).    The only way to have this 145° (72.5°*2) between each 2 of the 3 ants, is when they are not aligned over the same great circle (equator), but initially being aligned crocked to use 1.208333 * equator line, making a total of 435°. May be two of them could be over the equator.  The other three will make a different great circle inclination.